# Disabling Classic ASP without disabling ASP.NET on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

**BTW this is not something I am want but is a requirement I must follow**. My requirement is to create a user interface that will allow users to disable Classic ASP while allowing ASP.NET 1-4 applications run. Can anyone think of a use case were a user would want to do this?

Comment: Apart from cases where users only have .NET applications and no classic ASP applications?

Comment: AFAIK, the interface already exists to do it server-wide in IIS6+. Who are the target users if not administrators who can already use the existing tools?

Comment: @Oded My thing is if people only have .NET applications, why go through the hassle of disabling Classic ASP apps? Just do not include classic ASP code.

Comment: @Thomas. Admins and user should not directly interface with IIS, but with a web application to accomplish this.

Comment: A web interface to manage the server? Just make sure you don't write it in classic ASP....

Comment: @Robert - Are you basically trying to build something akin to Plesk to manage an IIS server?

Comment: Perhaps people want to _ensure_ that no one slips in a classic ASP page? Or if a vulnerability in classic ASP is found, the attack surface of the server/application is smaller.

Comment: Robert, because everything that allows code to be executed offers a new set of ways for the server to be compromised. It's Security 101 to turn off unneeded functionality on a server, so this would allow for that.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you were a web-host offering partial access to a webserver through an application that emulated some of the relevant IIS options, then not only would customers not want the added risk of unneeded script/executable systems running, but you wouldn't either, so you'd want it turned off unless they went in and explicitly turned it on because they needed it.

Indeed, software for this use-case already exists.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What kind of software has this functionality.

Comment: I've used web control panels to work shared servers before - I log into hosts' control panel system, I have access to the websites I'm running on it (and yes, including turning on or off ASP or ASP.NET, and for that matter PHP). Haven't used a shared-hosting system in a while, so I can't find the name, but there was more than one product out there doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Jon's comments about reducing a site's attack surface by removing unwanted features is very valid. You should ideally just run what you need and no more.

There are a number of ready made commercial solutions to this problem such as Plesk, but they may provide too much functionality for your needs.

You could write your own functionality:

If this is IIS6 then you should take a look at the ADSI API which is surfaced via the [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace:

[Using System.DirectoryServices to Configure IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

To enable/disable scriptmaps you need to manipulate the ScriptMaps metabase property for a site:

[ScriptMaps Metabase Property (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/45e717d0-20f6-459c-9183-cf6019f2edab.mspx?mfr=true)

If this is IIS7 then take a look at the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) managed API. In IIS7 you want to manipulate the handler mappings for a site:

[Handlers `<handlers>` - IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/handlers)

In all cases, the user must be a member of the machine's Administrators group.